# Numerical method for integral $\int_{a}^{b} p(x)/q(x) \ dx$

Tags: polynomials, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

Let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ be polynomials, I'm interested in this definite integral

$$I = \int_{a}^{b} \dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)} \ dx$$

**Question:** Are there numerical methods specifically to compute this kind of integral?

Normally I see the standard methods like Newton-cotes and Gaussian quadrature in the books, but I wonder if there are any for this kind

Comment: Do you know any additional information about the polynomials or is it just general

Comment: Partial fractions should help here to find the exact value, right? Or you are only interested in numerical approximation?

Comment: It seems that [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00211-009-0284-9) paper discusses a method for the entire real line

Comment: As general, but some hypothesis can be added if it helps, like $a = -b$ (symmetrical interval), or $q(x)$ has no zero or odd roots in $\left[a, \ b\right]$ and so on

Comment: @Vasili $q(x)$ being a polynomial of degree $n$, computing $I$ that way would require compute $n$ complex roots. It's a trade-off I cannot evaluate, but I will see if it leads somewhere